# linux - OOM / swap not being used

Tags: linux, swap, overlayfs

I am getting Out of Memory errors while my swap isn't touched.  I have 4GB of ram and 4GB of swap space.  I enabled the swap via swapon and when doing free, I see the swap listed there.

I'm thinking that perhaps there is some issue with overlayfs / tmpfs and swap all working together.  I have always had the opposite problem, trying to prevent swap usage, so I can't seem to figure out what changed.

Also, I am using a grsecurity enabled kernel.  Is it possible that memory allocation work differently under there?

Snapshot of free:

```
                      total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
          Mem:        3586392      157292       67052      141664     3362048     3236524
          Swap:       4194300           0     4194300
```

After I added the swap configuration to /etc/fstab, these numbers have changed; however, I still don't see any swap usage.  The only other thing I changed was the tmpfs size for /dev/shm and my overlayfs volume (/rw).  Both of which were not using much space to begin with, so the change should not have had any impact.

```
                      total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
          Mem:        3586392      571392     1714036      146096     1300964     2818004
          Swap:       4194300           0     4194300
```

I restarted a bunch of services and they're still running, and the biggest difference I see is that free memory is now showing 1.7GB free versus 67MB prior.

I'm still confused as to why that had any impact.  If I enable swap through swapon, it should behave the same way as if I configure it through /etc/fstab and do swapon -a.  Furthermore, it isn't even being used yet anyways.

Comment: have you checked if user-limits are in effect?
check with `ulimit -v` for a memory limit.

A second thought: if you are using a java program then you have to check the memory parameters of the java-vm.

Comment: I don't have user limits in effect, and I don't have a java program eating up the memory.  Why would that matter - don't I have a total of 8GB of memory that can be allocated roughly?

Comment: The jvm doesn't use all available memory. So if the program that gets an OOM is java-based, it is maybe limited by the jvm not the os.

Comment: I later got an OOM even after the above changes, so nothing really changed.

Comment: The peculiar thing is that I have about 3.2GB acting as a cache / buffer while only about 200MB is actually used according to free.  Memory usage / free space isn't being calculated properly, because, if the machine were truly out of memory, shouldn't the cache be discarded for actual use?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was a bug with the version of the kernel I was using.

Comment: It might help if you tell what kernel version it was, even better a link to the bug description.